# Gatling: How to access individual values in session arrays?

Tags: arrays, scala, gatling

I'm new to Gatling and Scala, and would appreciate some advice. Using the following code:

```
.check(
    regex(""""childClientIds":\["([^]]*)"""")
        .find
        .transform(_.split("""\",\"""").map(_.trim).toSeq)
        .saveAs("ChildClientIDs")
)
```

I've managed to save a list of IDs to the session variable ChildClientIDs. From the Gatling log:

`Session(Dashboard,1,Map(ChildClientIDs -> WrappedArray(ID1, ID2, ID3, etc.`

How can I access the individual elements in ChildClientIDs and use them in a request? `${ChildClientIDs}` will drop the entire array into the request, as expected. How can I just use the nth element in the array? `${ChildClientIDs}[n]` and `${ChildClientIDs[n]}` don't do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've answered my own question.

Per the documentation https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/session/expression_el/ `${ChildClientIDs(n)}`
is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use EL, for whatever reason, you can try this :

```
session => session("ChildClientIDs").as[Seq[String]].apply(indexOfElement)
```